# Do I need .CPP files at all? Use headers only and make everything inline?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, inline, header-files

GCC 4.6.1, specifically.

I am aware that CPP files serve to separate interface from implementation; that's not of interest right now.

Looking at [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html), I don't see any reason not to use only headers and all functions inline.

Performance is a concern, but I don't see that such an approach could make things slower. What I don't want, is to have critical sections which would usually be inlined, become slower because *everything* is inline. If that makes sense.

Comment: It's a common trick to concatenate all your source files into one giant source file for the release build... GCC has `-fwhole-program` to enable more radical optimisations in such a scenario. The new `-flto` does essentially the same thing without manual intervention. Don't worry about it too much and write your programs so that the next person can understand and continue them.

Comment: Well, technically the compiler doesn't give a damn about headers and implementation files - they're C files, some containing declarations and some containing definitions. But inlining everything doesn't improve performance - there's a reason compilers are rather careful about it (it clutters the cache, for instance).

Comment: What benefit do you think you will gain from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some reasons not to:

- No encapsulation; "internal" methods are visible to the entire program.
- Namespace pollution (leading to naming clashes or programmer error)
- Dependency problems; it becomes much harder to ensure everything's declared in the right order.
- Increased compilation times

Comment: 1. Encapsulation - that shouldn't be an issue at all. See [this part of the C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/classes-and-objects.html#faq-7.8).
2. To solve this, just write your code in different namespace...

Comment: @user1071136: I'm not talking about security.

Comment: Oh. Then what? if a method is `private` it doesn't really matter it's visible, unless you're concerned with security. No ?

Comment: @user1071136: I'm talking about presenting a well-defined interface, rather than security.  Perhaps I mean "accessible" rather than "visible".  Not all functions are member functions...

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is compilation time, really.

If everything is included into a single "master" compilation unit, then everything has to be recompiled if you change a single character in a single file.

On the other hand, a full rebuild will very likely be *faster* than if you'd used multiple compilation units (in which case, the same headers would have to be compiled multiple times, and the linker would have more work to do. With a single compilation unit, each header only needs to be processed once, and the linker's job is pretty trivial)

With multiple .cpp files, you can make a change in one of them, and only have to recompile *that* file.

But several popular libraries are header-only. It's definitely viable.

Performance-wise, it should be the same or faster. You're giving the compiler full visibility over your entire code, which means it can easily optimize across function calls, and inline anything it likes.

And note that you're never *forcing* the compiler to inline. The `inline` keyword (and other tricks which have the same effect) do not tell the compiler that "this must be inlined". But by suppressing the one-definition-rule (ODR), they allow you to include a definition into multiple compilation units, and so it becomes easier for the compiler to inline, *if it chooses to do so*.

But that means you don't need to worry about everything being inlined. The compiler will only inline as much as it makes sense to do.

Answer (score 2):

Performance and inlining aside, there are things you can't do with headers-only, such as `static` fields of a class.

That said, most (if not all) of `STL` is headers-only, as is most of `Boost`.

As for inline methods/functions - it doesn't really matter. The compiler knows better than you what to do, and may ignore `inline` keywords (making a function non-inline) or to the contrary, make a function call inline even if the function wasn't declared as such.

Answer (score 0):

If all functions will be "inline" then yours binary file will be bigger and this could lead to less performance. You should inline only very small and often called functions.

Comment: You should leave it up to the compiler to decide.

Comment: There's a difference between the compiler's inlining optimization and the `inline` keyword. Marking all functions `inline` does not mean that all functions will be inlined.